# Android : Diferencia entre handleActionRun y onHandleIntent (IntentService)

Tags: android, intentservice

Cuál es la diferencia entre estos 2 métodos. He creado un **Intent Service** y no sé bien donde debo realizar las acciones. ¿ Alguien me podría explicar de forma sencilla estos dos métodos ?

Comment: Revisa este articulo, te puede ayudar; http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/tareas-en-segundo-plano-en-android-ii-intentservice/ Es parecido a un Asynctask

Comment: Gracias, pero ese artículo sólo habla sobre el onHandleIntent.